# How to make express js and socket io listen to different ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my socket io and Node express js server both listen to same ports now. Its hosted in AWS ElasticBeanStalk. Its working good.
Now due to security restrictions , have to move socket io to different port. Its a part of the same code base as of node js app. 
Can I listen to a different port for socket io? Will that work ?What changes will I have to do in ElasticBeanStalk? Any new ports has to be opened Or is there any restriction in the port?

Comment: What security restrictions cause you to have to move socket.io to a different port from your web server?  Usually security restrictions LIKE both to be on the same port.  That's the whole reason that websocket/socket.io was designed to share a port with an http server.

Comment: Socket io is just used for Event publishing .So it need not to be secured in our use case. Our node App is fully secured and it needs authorization bearer token. And Port on which node is working is exposed to only the API manager. So the socket io should be in a different port to bypass API Manager

Comment: You can certainly just listen on a different port for socket.io in your same node.js app.  For a regular socket.io connection (the default connection that starts with a few polling requests), you may also have to enable CORS if the connection is being made from a browser so the browser will allow the connection to a port that is different from the web page.  Or, you could change the socket.io client to immediately start with webSocket which is not restricted by CORS.  I can't help on what AWS changes would be needed to use a new port.

Comment: AFAIK they are only bound to the same port if you use socket.io via its express implementation. If you separate those two, you can choose whatever port you like for socket.io, but it won't automatically deliver the JS file to the front end.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://socket.io/docs/) give examples of connecting via Express *or* via standard Node HTTP. So technically you can just meld both of them together and listen on different ports.

```
var exApp = require('express')();
var exServer = require('http').Server(exApp);

var ioApp = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(ioApp);

exServer.listen(80);
ioApp.listen(81);

function handler (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200).end({});
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// Then whatever you want to do with `io`, and `exApp`.
```

If you go to `localhost:80`, you'll get the Express app served, and if you send socket.io requests to `localhost:81`, it should trigger the `io.connection()`

I haven't technically tested this, so let me know if I'm wildly off and I'll further think about it.

Comment: I am more interested in the configuration changes in elasticbean stalk and may be in the nginx

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?